# Wordpress Custom Post Type for Site Background Color

Tags: wordpress

My client has asked for me to add a section within their Wordpress CMS that will enable them to change the site background color and header div background color of the site.

I've been searching and cannot find any tutorials that show how to do this.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that changing the background colour can be done by default for most themes 
via Appearance -> Customise.

However, you can extend the customiser functionality further in your own theme by using the API:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to go to "Appearance > Background", this is available in most of the themes. You can select the background image, or background color that way. The header however, some themes might only let you change the header image.

If you want to have better customization of your background, you can always change it through Stylesheet or put it directly on the HTML tag.

Note that wordpress blogs (the ones that hosted on wordpress.com blog service) won't have the access to the Stylesheet unless using paid features.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I ended up using. I installed the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and created two custom field: one for background left and one for background right. This is so that my user could choose a different color background for each side of the homepage banner area.

I was then able to set these custom fields up within the homepage edit screen (in Wordpress) as 2 separate color pickers.

Finally, within my page-homepage.php template, I could target the values of those custom fields in this way:

`<div class="slideshowBgLeft" style="background-color:<?the_field( 'home_background_color_left' );?>">
    </div>`

`<div class="slideshowBgRight" style="background-color:<?the_field( 'home_background_color_right' );?>">
    </div>`

I would definitely recommend this plug if you're looking for lots of options with custom post types.